# Not able to add "tabs" permission in manifest.json file on chrome webstore

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, permissions

I am trying to upload my chrome extension on chrome web-store with below permissions:

```
"permissions" : [ "nativeMessaging", "tabs", "http://*google.com/*" ],
```

An error occurred: Failed to process your item.

```
The field permissions.http://*.google.com/* is not allowed in manifest.
The field permissions.tabs is not allowed in manifest.
```

======================================================================

I also tried using:

```
"optional_permissions" : [ "tabs", "http://*google.com/*" ],
```

and trying to access these access to get optional permission with below API: "chrome.permissions.request"

But I have following questions:

1. How to get 'tabs" permission?
2. If I declare these in optional permission then extension get submitted but I not able to get additional permission prompt.
3. I found chrome permission API  "chrome.permissions.request" - https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions. I tried to call this with my custom page but getting error "Cannot read property 'request' of undefined"

Comment: please include your manifest.json

Comment: This sounds like a typo: make sure you didn't write `"permissions" : { "stuff" }` instead of `[ "stuff" ]`.

Comment: `http://*google.com/*` is the culprit, you must use `http://*.google.com/*`.

Comment: @RobW Read the error message; I think my theory fits better, and period omission is just a typo.

Comment: @Xan The error message described a semantic error. Such errors can only be reported if the input was parsed successfully, i.e. when there are no syntax errors. Your guess is syntactically invalid, so I have ruled out that possibility already after reading the comment.

Comment: @Pravin Any chance that you're trying to upload an *app* instead of an extension? Could you show your whole manifest file?

Comment: hear it is manifest.json


{
  "name": "My Extension",
  "short_name": "my custom extension",
  "version": "1.4",
  "description": "urls contains 'mysite' in them.",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
   "app": {
    "launch": {
      "local_path": "main.html"
    }
  },
 "permissions" : [ "nativeMessaging", "tabs" ],
 "optional_permissions": [ ],
 "externally_connectable": {
  "matches": ["*://*.mysite.com/*"]
 },
  "icons" : {
 "16" : "icon-16.png",
    "48" : "icon-48.png",
    "128" : "icon-128.png"
  },
  
  "manifest_version": 2
}